# How to search for a keyword in different pandas dataframe and update or create a new column with matching keyword in parent DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example,
parent pandas df is as follow

[image]

Now I have another df, df_keywords

[image]

What I want to do is, check if any of the keyword from df_keywords['Keywords to Search'] is present is df['Description'] and create a new column as df['Keywords'], for example..

[image]

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, just stuck on how to approach the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to create a helper column on `df` with the keyword matching `Keywords to Search` in `df_keywords`. Then, merge `df` with `df_keywords` on the keywords, as follows:

```
keywords = df_keywords['Keywords to Search'].dropna().unique()

df['keyword'] = df['Description'].map(lambda x: np.nan if (pd.isna(x) or len(w:=[y for y in keywords if y in str(x)]) == 0) else w[0])
```

Result:

```
print(df)

     Description keyword
0   I have a dog     dog
1   I have a cat     cat
2  I want coffee  coffee
3   I need sleep   sleep
```

Then, merge the 2 dataframes with `.merge()` matching the keywords:

```
df_out = df.merge(df_keywords, left_on='keyword', right_on='Keywords to Search')
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

     Description keyword Keywords to Search Keywords to Update
0   I have a dog     dog                dog        dog related
1   I have a cat     cat                cat        cat related
2  I want coffee  coffee             coffee     coffee related
3   I need sleep   sleep              sleep      sleep related
```

Finally, remove unwanted columns and rename column,

```
df_out = df_out.drop(['keyword', 'Keywords to Search'], axis=1).rename({'Keywords to Update': 'Keywords'}, axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

     Description        Keywords
0   I have a dog     dog related
1   I have a cat     cat related
2  I want coffee  coffee related
3   I need sleep   sleep related
```

Comment: Tbh, I'm not really familiar using lambda functions. Ran into an error
"argument type 'float' is not iterable". Also, just discovered that the keywords to search may not always be single words and could be two or three words.

Comment: I replaced the last x with str(x). Works now. Thanks!

Comment: @RiteshKankonkar  Oh, missed your previous comment, sorry!   Your `Description` column has some non-string values ?  Or `NaN` values ?  Anyway, great that it works now.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong, it worked for the first time and now it throws an error as
"TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float". Converting the keyword variable in str also doesn't help.

Comment: @RiteshKankonkar  You can also drop the `NaN` entries in column `Keywords to Search` by `keywords = df_keywords['Keywords to Search'].dropna().unique()`

Comment: @RiteshKankonkar  I've simulated your error case.  It' really is owing to `NaN` values in column `Keywords to Search`.   See my edit above with `.dropna()` on the statment:  `keywords = df_keywords['Keywords to Search'].dropna().unique()`  Tested no problem with this.

Comment: RIght, just tried this. Works perfectly fine. Again, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it. This won't work if description contains more than 1 keyword, and may not be the fasted if you have a lot of words to check.

What I've done is create a blank 'Keywords to Search' column in `df_parent`, then gone through each keyword, and checked if the keyword exists in in the 'Description' column using `df_parent['Description'].str.contains(keyword)`. Then I've replaced any True values with the keyword, and false with nan and used this new series to fill in the Nan's in my new 'Keywords to Search' column in the parent dataframe. This then returns a filled in 'Keywords to Search' column in `df_parent` with the keyword corresponding to the description of that row.  Then I've merged `df_parent` and `df_keywords` on the 'Keywords to Search' column, and then dropped it to get the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_parent = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['I have a dog', 'I have a cat', 'I want coffee', 'I need sleep']})

df_keywords = pd.DataFrame({'Keywords to Search' : ['cat', 'sleep', 'dog', 'coffee'],
                            'Keywords to Update' : ['cat related', 'sleep related', 'dog related', 'coffee related']})

df_parent['Keywords to Search'] = np.nan
for keyword in df_keywords['Keywords to Search']:
    df_parent['Keywords to Search'].fillna(df_parent['Description'].str.contains(keyword)
                                        .replace({True:keyword, False:np.nan}), inplace=True)

output = df_parent.merge(df_keywords, on='Keywords to Search').drop('Keywords to Search', axis=1)
```

output:

```
     Description Keywords to Update
0   I have a dog        dog related
1   I have a cat        cat related
2  I want coffee     coffee related
3   I need sleep      sleep related
```